# Functioning/ Error Handling of WebView

Tags: java, error-handling, webview

Firstly, I am a newbie in webview so mind if I am asking a stupid question.

What I am doing here is to open a URL on a panel through webview and till now I am successfully doing it, for both local files and internet URL as well, but just needed to know if there is any mechanism from webview side to do the error handling stuff itself.

Like for example, if I put a wrong URL or the added URL is taking time to load or even if there is no Internet Connection, in all these cases, webview doesn't prompt me any error and I have to handle all these exceptions manually.

Please help me and let me know what can be done or if there is any documents or books that can be referred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply but what exactly am looking for is Webview Loadworker's progress/workdone property... Though I finally got my answer and by adding listeners to its property, I was also able to determine the exception occurred if any...

Click [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=9979523) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip, since i don't use webview in my current projects.
Have you tried with

```
onReceivedError
```

?

```
WebView wv = your veiw;
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   @Override
   public void onReceivedError(WebView pView, int pErrorCode, String pDescription, String pFailingUrl) {
           Log.i("put your messaage here");
           super.onReceivedError(pView, pErrorCode, pDescription, pFailingUrl);
   }
});
```

If you use many webview you can write your own class that extends WebViewClient, and write all the checks you need only once (maybe you would like to test if the connection to internet is prresent, or some other things)